# Mudar imagem de posição com transição ao passar mouse sobre ela?

Tags: html, css

Quero uma imagem que esta em `float:right` vá para `float:left`, mas com algum tipo de transição.

Comment: matheus, qual a sua duvida em relação a isso? voce começou a escrever algum código? pode compartilhar conosco?

Comment: eu criei uma div com uma imagen dentro e fiz o seguinte la no css eu coloquei a imagen dentro da div em FLOAT RIGHT e depois coloquei a opção DIV;HOVER para a imagen ir para FLOAT LEFT deu certo so que eu queria fazer ele rolar de um lado a outro com uma trasição

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Float não é "animável", mas você pode conseguir algo do tipo usando posição absoluta e variando o `left`:

```css
#area {
  position:relative;
  overflow:auto;
}

#area img {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:0;
  left:0;
  margin-left:0;
  transition:2s;
}

#area:hover img {
  left:100%;
  margin-left:-100px; // mesma largura da imagem
}

img {background:purple;width:100px;height:100px}
```

```html
<div id="area">
  <img>
</div>
```

**Considerações:**

- Caso queira compatibilidade com navegadores antigos, pode mudar a `div` para `a`, para que o `:hover` funcione;
- o `:hover` pode ser aplicado diretamente no `img`, mas neste caso a pessoa pode ter que acompanhar o objeto com o mouse, senão ao se mover, o `:hover` deixa de atuar;
- da mesma forma, se passar o `:hover` para a imagem, e quiser que funcione com navegadores mais antigos, precisa fazer um bloco `a` interno, e usar a imagem embutida nesse bloco.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do hover insira um `transition: 5s;` e coloque quantos segundos desejar para que a transição seja feita.. você ainda pode adicionar um `transform: rotate(720deg);` que sua imagem vai ir rodando de um lado para o outro, onde o valor de deg é quantos graus você quer que este elemento gire...